# c++ How do I stop my loop from spitting out the last input twice

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, fstream

I am doing a banking program and in my deposit function I have the following code which reads from a text file and stores the amounts into famount.
The only problem is that when I run the program and it outputs famount, the line prior has the exact same data as the line above it.

This is the piece of code.

```
file>>firstname>>lastname;
cout<<endl<<firstname<<" "<<lastname<<endl;
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
{
    //stringstream the getline for line string in file
    istringstream iss(line);
    file>>date>>amount;
    iss >> date >> amount;


    cout<<date<<"\t\t"<<amount<<endl;
    famount+=amount;

    // I tried to use this to stop reading after 
    // to the file ends but it still reads the last 
    // data on the file twice.
    if(file.eof()){
        break;
    }
}
cout<<famount;
```

The text file looks like this:

Tony Gaddis

05/24/12    100

05/30/12    300

07/01/12    -300

//Console Output looks like this

Tony Gaddis

05/24/12    100

05/30/12    300

07/01/12    -300

07/01/12    -300      //This shouldn't be here!!!!!

-200                      //It should result in 100

What can I do to correct this and why is it happening.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "mumble mumble twice" -> `eof()` abuse. Don't use `eof()`. It makes no sense. Check your input operations instead.

Comment: `file>>date>>amount; iss >> date >> amount;` You're extracting twice, once from file, once from stringstream. Why?

Comment: I'm still trying to see how this code generates that output with that input. .. and I'm still not seeing it. If anything I expect it to output *less* data than you want, not more, for no other specific reason than the extraneous `file>>date>>amount` *inside* the loop that you apparently neglected to remove when you added per-line processing. Wait... now I see it.

Comment: @WhozCraig if he got an empty last line in the input the getline in the while condition will succeed but he won't be able to extract the date and amount from the stringstream that got set to an empty line.

Comment: @Tribse yeah, that was what I was thinking. just took me a minute to realize after even the first `getline`is wrong, and subsequent `getline` calls are always reading just the leftover newline after the erroneously placed extractions (+1 on your answer, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to change your code into:

```
file>>firstname>>lastname;
cout<<endl<<firstname<<" "<<lastname<<endl; 
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
{
    //stringstream the getline for line string in file
    istringstream iss(line);
    // file>>date>>amount; // that line seems a bit off...
    if (iss >> date >> amount;) // it would have failed before when line was an empty last line.
    {

        cout<<date<<"\t\t"<<amount<<endl;
        famount+=amount;
    }

}
cout<<famount;
```

before if `getline(file, line)` read an empty last line, it would return true and enter the while block. Later your `iss >> date >> amount` would fail within the while block since the `stringstream` would be set only to that empty line, therefore you'd repeat outputing the date and amount frome the line before.

Remember that if you have to checking for `eof()` there almost always is something wrong...

Comment: +1 This is clearly the correct way to do this for per-line handling, and the analysis of how this lead to a duplicate last line (which it would even without the `file.eof()` invoke in the original code), was an interesting brain-cersise.

Comment: "// file>>date>>amount; // that line seems a bit off..."-Tribse. Lol yea im trying to teach myself to code, so I make random mistakes like that. But I do appreciate your help, a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2934783 it is honestly ironic that that mistake lead to the per-line validation doing exactly the *opposite* of what you intended.